# Python imaplib: can't find a message with .search, but works if I hardcode the search

Tags: python, imaplib

This is driving me nuts. If I use this code:

```
while msgnums == ['']:  # wait until message list from server isn't empty
    typ, msgnums = gmail.m.uid('search', None, 'To', new_user)
    print '\n', new_user, sec_waiting, typ, msgnums
```

The output is:

```
qatestdata+auto20111104113143@gmail.com 300 OK ['']
```

In other words, it's not finding my message. BUT, if I hard code it like this:

```
typ, msgnums = gmail.m.uid('search', None, 'To', 'qatestdata+auto20111104113143@gmail.com')
```

The output is:

```
qatestdata+auto20111104113844@gmail.com 0 OK ['19']
```

(It finds the message.) new_user is a string. I don't understand why it's not working.

I have also tried:

```
search_string = '(To \"' + created_username + '\")'
while msg_uid == ['']:  # wait until message list from server isn't empty
    resp, msg_uid = gmail.m.search(None, search_string)
```

But it fails too.

Comment: The above produces a SyntaxError, something is wrong with the quotes in your gmail.m.search call.

Comment: Assuming `new_user` is a variable, it shouldn't be quotes.  Your second line should read `typ, msgnums = gmail.m.search(None, 'TO', new_user)`

Comment: I've tried with just new_user, but it still doesn't find the message. I also corrected the quotes per themel's comment and it still fails.

Comment: What does `new_user` contain?

Comment: new_user is simply a string, qatestdata+auto20111104113143@gmail.com in the example above -- so hardcoding that string works, and I can see it in the inbox, but for some reason I can't use a variable to specify it. Makes no sense to me.

Comment: I solved it. My automation was checking for the message too quickly. And simply putting a `gmail.m.select('[Gmail]/All Mail')` **inside** my while loop made it refresh the message set I was working with.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solve it with some changes at the sting quotes.

I want to search that:

```
resp, items = m.search(None, '(FROM "*" SUBJECT "<root@doire> test.sh > /dev/null")')
```

The hard coded works but the loop didn't work although it seem right.

```
    email_subjects_with_del = [ "<root@doire> test.sh > /dev/null" ]

    for sub in email_subjects_with_del:
        text = "%s%s%s" % ("'(FROM \"*\" SUBJECT \"", sub, "\")'")

        print text
        resp, items = m.search(None, text )
```

But this works (without the ' quotes)

```
    for sub in email_subjects_with_del:
        text = "%s%s%s" % ("(FROM \"*\" SUBJECT \"", sub, "\")")

        print text
        resp, items = m.search(None, text )
```